# How can I connect My Domain and Spring-boot project?

Tags: amazon-ec2, domain, httpd, httpd.conf, springboot

**my env** : Linux, maven, AWS EC2, Spring boot

I can see the main screen of the project when I connect to the Elastic IP of EC2. However, when I try to connect to the purchased .dev domain, I get an **403 error** and **Test Page of Apache**.

I think, maybe I didn't enter the correct path. Or, The permission setting is incorrect.

So I modified the httpd.conf file, but it still doesn't solve the problem. Can you check which one is wrong?

**Please Check my Code**

The path to the file that needs to be executed is in "/home/ec2-user/project/src/main/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp".

**etc/httpd/conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/home/ec2-user"
    ServerName "test.dev"
    ServerAlias "www.test.dev"
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.dev/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.dev/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

```
# set IP addresses

Listen 80
    
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/ec2-user"
    ServerName "test.dev"
    ServerAlias "www.test.dev"
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.test.dev [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =test.dev
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>


# set Deny entirety <- default

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>


# Directory custom setting

DocumentRoot "/home/ec2-user"

<Directory "/home/ec2-user">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/ec2-user">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Index position custom setting
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex /project/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp
</IfModule>
```

**Error log**

```
[core:error] [pid 7748] (13)Permission denied: [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] 
AH00035: access to /project/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp denied 
(filesystem path '/home/ec2-user/project/src') because search permissions are 
missing on a component of the path
```

ec2-user's permissions
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03tQr.png)

project's permissions
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WFQs.png)

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved through struggling!
I will share the situation I solved!
First of all, the direction of approach was wrong from the start.

It was correct in my situation. Entering the path **'home/ec2-user'** into the **DocumentRoot**. See the code below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/ec2-user"
    ServerName "test.dev"
    ServerAlias "www.test.dev"
    ~
</VirtualHost>
```

The httpd configuration should only be done up to this point.
After that, changed all connections that access http (80 port) with Nginx to https (port 443).